# Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose, fedora

So I tried to start docker with sudo systemctl start docker but it says this:
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.

I'm using Fedora 36. The thing is, when I try docker version or docker compose version it tells me that they are installed and when I tried to unistall them with
sudo yum remove docker-ce

It told me this:
No match for argument: docker-ce
No packages marked for removal.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

I have no idea what to do..